# delete three columns of two grouped columns according to common value of two column

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 sets of three grouped columns in one worksheet. This stretches for 30000 rows. Sample data is below:

I want a macro Do like this code :
Code:

```
when (old serial)=(new serial) then delete (new code) AND (new serial) AND(new amount)

old code    old serial  old amount  new code    new serial  new amount
  1           11             100       2            12         2000
  2           12             200       1            11         1000
  3           13             300       2            200        2000
  4           14             400       4            400        4000
```

table after algorithm is below :

```
old code    old serial  old amount  new code    new serial  new amount
1             11             100        2            200      2000
2             12             200        4            400      4000
3             13             300            
4             14             400
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your data looks like this and all the entries in "New Serial" Column are unique, here's the solution:

[image]

```
Sub test()
Set ExcelAppl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
Set Rng = ws.UsedRange
RowCount = Rng.Rows.Count
For i = 1 To RowCount
OldSerial = Cells(i, 2).Value
'assign the column range of "new serial" that you want to find
With ws.Range("E:E")
Set C = .Find(OldSerial, LookIn:=xlValues)
If Not C Is Nothing Then
rowNumber = C.Row
colNumber = C.Column
'delete new serial
Cells(rowNumber, colNumber).Value = ""
'delete new code
Cells(rowNumber, colNumber - 1).Value = ""
'delete new amount
Cells(rowNumber, colNumber + 1).Value = ""
End If
End With
Next
Set Rng = Nothing
Set ws = Nothing
Set wb = Nothing

End Sub
```

Output will be:

[image]

Comment: tahnks.raj.for your answer.but this macro cant work for some condition like when the old seial and new serial are' not in front of together like the table  i updated.cant you develop your vb code to solve that.! thnx....!

Comment: Are these "Old Serial" or"New Serial" values unique?? @shahram

Comment: yes @raj they are unique. and i want to delete old one.

Comment: your code is good as old and new serial in same row .but i test that for example when  old seial(11) in first row and new serial (11) in second row.and it did not work.!. :)

Comment: I have updated the solution, now it will work even if you have old serial and new serial in different rows. But I am pretty confused with your requirement. You mentioned in the question you want to delete "new code","new serial", "new amount" but in the previous comment you mentioned, you want to delete old one. My code should work for questions's requirement.

Comment: It would me more appreciable, if you mark the answer as "accepted", when you feel someone answers your question correctly.  Please see [How to accept answer] (http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)